# How to write bash script with options with arguments? Standalone use or stdin from pipe

Tags: bash, shell-script

How can I write a bash script that can either take stdin from pipe or be used standalone but also allow options with arguments for either case?

Example:

```
./myscript.sh -t mytitle -m mymessage
Send message with -t title and -m message
```

or

```
somecommand | myscript.sh -t mytitle
output from somecommand gets used as message
```

Solution can use ifne as well

Comment: You're essentially looking for a default value for `-m` that would read from standard input?

Comment: More or less, yes. If myscript is being piped to then -m would come from standard input. Otherwise if run on its own, I would provide -m.

Comment: What if you're piping to stdin and also provided `-m` ?

Comment: @Ginnungagap I would be inclined to say that `-m` provides an option and without it the utility reads from _stdin_. There is precedent for this

Comment: @roaima I wouldn't mind if it worked this way, if -m is not provided than read from stdin.

Comment: Read `man getopt getopts` for option parsing. Otherwise,  just read `STDIN`. It's setup by the parent process. Normally, one neither knows nor cares where `STDIN` comes from, one of the wonderful design decisions of Unix. I've programmed on systems where one had to specify a different set of paramrters for disks and magtapes, and the program had handle them differently.

Comment: Show us what you already got. Try to do at least some of what you need, [edit] your question and add your initial code so the answer won't have to be a code from scratch, and it will also show us what you already tried to do.